# Net Start OracleXETNSListner

Tags: oracle-11g

I am trying to run Oracle Express Edition on Windows 7 and getting the following error.

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\1O.2.O\server\BIN>net start OracleXETNSListener  
    System error 5 has occurred. 
    Access is denied.
    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\1O.2.O\server\BIN>net start OracleServiceXE  
    System error 5 has occurred. 
    Access is denied. 
    C :\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\1O. 2 .O\server\BIN>_
```

How I can fix this?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any error. It helps if you can copy/paste the error text.

Comment: @ik_zelf - I have attached the screen shot showing the error, can't you see that?

Comment: Now I can see it. Maybe I was to quick. Do you have administrator privileges?

Comment: I'v extracted text from attached image and updated the question. @itsaboutcode - posting error codes will help others to provide correct solution for you.

Comment: @ik_zelf - Yah I have. It was working when I installed it. Now I am checking like after 2 weeks and getting this error.

Comment: are you on a dhcp client? How does you listener.ora and sqlnet.ora look like? What is your ip-address? (is it in sync with what is in listener.ora?) Do you have firewalls enabled?

Comment: @ik_zelf - Sorry don't know what you mean, it's installed on my local machine.

Comment: Can you list the listener.ora, sqlnet.ora and show your ip-address? Normally clients use dhcp and have a dynamic ip-address. If it a previous address is in the listener.ora this could be your problem.

Comment: @ik_zelf - Thanks for your help but I have fix the issue by reinstalling it... Really don't know what was the issue but it has been fixed for now.

Answer (score 5):

Access service management console via `Run->services.msc`.
Locate  `OracleXETNSListener` service from the list, `Right click and open 'properties'` window.
See `Log On`tab, update `Log On as` account, normally `Network Service` will do the trick if `Local System` account is not working for you.